# Accessing Controllers methods for sidebar in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-blade

I am making a project with Laravel 5.6 and at the moment I am making a sidebar with links to access the functionality of specified controller. f.e. if I am in posts blade, it will show PostsController methods for the sidebar.

The problem is that every controller has different amount of methods, and I wouldn't want to make a mess with 10 different static layouts for sidebars.

Is there a way to access controller methods thru functionality that returns all methods of the controller to a view?

Or am I thinking this wrong.. If someone knows a better solution for this i'm all ears. :)

I know I can install packages for functionality but I want to know before that is there any simple solution.

## EDIT1:

get_class_methods($this) returns following value:

[Returned Methods of a Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3pvz.png)

I can add a validator that checks if "index" or "create" is present. Guess my problem was solved, thank you all who answered.

## EDIT2:

The code that dumps the returned methods.

```
public function index()
{

    $events = Event::all();

    dd($controller = get_class_methods($this));

    return view('events.index', compact(['events', 'controller']));

}
```

Comment: A controller is a class, you can use "get_class_methods" function to get all methods.

Comment: You can create object of the class by providing full namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ´get_cass_methods´ function to grab all the methods on the controller class

```
function index() {
  $methods = get_class_methods($this);
  return view('posts', compact('methods'));
}
```

if you want to filter out methods from the parent class

```
function index() {
  $methods = array_diff(get_class_methods($this),get_class_methods(get_parent_class()));
  return view('posts', compact('methods'));
}
```

Comment: If I ask for methods that way, it returns a bunch of classes that are inbuilt in Laravel. I will update the return message to main question.

Comment: @TuomasTuokkola Can you share an example of your code?

Comment: What part of the code do you want to see? I can update to the main post the code that dumped the code. I've checked all the data goes all the way to view.

Comment: @TuomasTuokkola See my updated answer.. it filteres out the inherited methods from the array.

Comment: Thank you! This was the best experience I've had in stackoverflow. :)